# Can't install wine on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, wine, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I cannot install Wine on Ubuntu 14.04.  When I try to install it on the Ubuntu Software Center I always get a message that says I have unmet dependencies. I tried installing Wine through the terminal and I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

[Source](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/wine)

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal by press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type this following on terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

That's it

Comment: I did as above and got this...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.38-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then just try installing again.