# Unable to install wine on ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, wine, 64-bit, winetricks

I am using following article to fix this issue:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246183

This is the output I get:

```
aditya@aditya-Vostro-3446:~/$ sudo apt-get purge wine
[sudo] password for aditya: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
aditya@aditya-Vostro-3446:~/$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
aditya@aditya-Vostro-3446:~/$ 
aditya@aditya-Vostro-3446:~/$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And when I try to install wine using ubuntu software center I get following message:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
q4wine: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.9 is to be installed
        Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
        Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
        Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
        Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
```

Comment: @karel please see this comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/575706/unable-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?noredirect=1#comment794582_575707 Do you still feel its a duplicate?

Comment: Also try this one: [Can't install wine on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459280/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.` means that you have 41 upgrade pending. First try cleaning out packages you do not need `sudo apt-get autoremove`. Then update your system `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. If there still are some packages not installed, go with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Note, that this command will **remove packages** conflicting with the ones being installed, favouring more important ones. Try again `sudo apt-get install wine`.

Comment: The actual problem is: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. I suggest you begin by following @julka advice in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

To force install the dependencies and such.

Or try installing it via the [Ubuntu Wine Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Comment: this is what i get in the end by using the ppa method:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running `AMD64` or `i386`? Or you can try to Install `wine1.7-i386` then? like so: `sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386`!

Comment: hmmm:: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libfontconfig:i386
                     Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Comment: AMD64 or i386??

Comment: uname output: Linux aditya-Vostro-3446 3.5.0-54-generic #81~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I believe it is 64... but why wont it even install why software center..

Comment: `sudo apt-get install wine:i386`? This issues is related to [What happened to the ia32-libs package?](http://askubuntu.com/q/107230/36315) and [How do you run a 32-bit program on a 64-bit version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/359156/36315)

Comment: Do I need to install openjdk for wine to work?

Comment: I get:  icedtea-netx : Depends: openjdk-6-jre (>= 6b23~pre10~) but it is not going to be installed or
                         openjdk-7-jre but it is not going to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Try to install directly the last version:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

or (previous version):

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score -1):

you need to reinstall package ttf-mscorefonts-installer because by default the license for this package is not accepted, you need to manually accept the license for this package."Microsoft's core fonts package has unmet dependencies in wine.

"first remove them from your system as

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then re-install

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then accept the license using tab key in a graphical interface after doing this install any version of wine,you can install wine from software centre .This package is also required if you want to install adobe flash player plugin.Note: wine1.6.2 is the stable release and Wine 1.7.34 is the latest wine release as of now.You can refer to

[wine HQ](https://www.winehq.org/download/)