# Unable to Install Wine on Ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, wine, winetricks

It's giving me following error mentioned below after trying to install wine v1.7 on ubuntu 14.04.2:

```
 libgbm1 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri
 libudev1 : Depends: libcgmanager0 but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2)
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1)
           Recommends: cups-bsd
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: How are you installing Wine? Are you using `apt-get` or a .deb file?

Comment: Just use playonlinux, which manages any desired wine version, depending on what you want to install and works fine with the Ubuntu default bundled version of wine.

Comment: @errikos: PoL still depends on Wine and transitively on its dependencies.

Comment: @Ankit See this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/575706/unable-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

It will install the supported wine package in your Ubuntu machine

Comment: my mistake.. edited